# Is it possible to replace iframes with video element in kaltura

Tags: kaltura

I need to get rid of the iframes in the website but I have some videos from kaltura which provides embed code kWidget.embed which in turns provide iframes.

Is there any way to replace the iframe with video element in kWidget.embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - with Kaltura new player version we dont use iframes any more.
https://developer.kaltura.com/player

Comment: For existing videos in the website is it possible to convert the kWidget object to player?